# Drawing dots and lines on to a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, core-graphics

I gave myself an exercise to learn Swift, based on an example I have found on the Apple Swift [website](http://www.apple.com/swift/):

[image]

As you can see there's a river and a few dots in it right in the middle, forming a path. So I have started looking for a similar river image on the internet and I have created a Xcode playground. This is what I have now:

[image]

So basically I have an `UIView` with a subview consisting in the river image I have found and a dot made with `UIBezierPath`.

My **first** question is: is this the right way to drawn on to a UIView? I mean using a `UIBezierPath`. And my **second** question is: how do I draw the dot at a precise coordinate inside the `UIView`? (`UIBezierPath` or everything else?)

Just to be more precise, my intent here is to make an algorithm to make the program recognize the image and based on the pixel color it would draw a line with dots from the start to the end of the river, passing between it's middle.

Comment: It's completely ok here to use UIBezierPaths and CAShapeLayers to draw the circles and 'connect the dots'. UIBezierPath has many methods such as `moveToPoint:` to allow you to draw the line. The CAShapeLayer can then represent that line so that you can add attributes such as stroke width, colors etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To draw `UIBezierPath` on `UIView` do this:

```
let xCoord = 10
let yCoord = 20
let radius = 8

let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(xCoord, yCoord, radius, radius))

let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = dotPath.CGPath
layer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

drawingView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

This code will draw a dot with radius 8 with coordinates 10,20 on your view.

**Update: Swift 4+**

```
let xCoord = 10
let yCoord = 20
let radius = 8

let dotPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: xCoord, y: yCoord, width: radius, height: radius))

let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = dotPath.cgPath
layer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

drawingView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt at the lines part of the equation:

```
    var offset:CGFloat    = 0;    var squareWidth:Int = 20
    var squareRows:Int    = Int(view.frame.size.width/CGFloat(squareWidth))
    var squareColumns:Int = Int(view.frame.size.height/CGFloat(squareWidth))

    for (index,element) in (0...squareRows).enumerate(){
        for (column,element) in (0...squareColumns).enumerate(){
            // Build The Square
            let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(
                view.frame.minX + CGFloat(squareWidth * index) - offset,
                view.frame.minY + CGFloat(column * squareWidth), 20, 20
                ),
                cornerRadius: 0.00)

            // Style Square
            let a = CAShapeLayer()
                a.path = rectanglePath.CGPath
                a.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                a.fillColor = nil
                a.opacity = 0.3
                a.lineWidth = 1.5
            view.layer.insertSublayer(a, atIndex: 1)
        }
    }
```

[image: View Rendered with layers]