# How to draw to CAShapeLayer in a UIView independently?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I am continuing in my Swift homework I have stared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206056/drawing-dots-and-lines-on-to-a-uiview) (previous Stack**Overflow** question). But I'm facing a new problem now. Finally I am able to draw dots on my river image just by using a `UIBezierPath` and a `CAShapeLayer` using the code below (with the help of @**[njuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3741795/njuri)**):

```
import UIKit

let beginPoint = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(130, 360, 20, 20))
let endPoint = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(260, 57, 20, 20))

let drawingView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 400))
drawingView.addSubview(UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "River.jpeg")))

let drawingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
drawingLayer.path = beginPoint.CGPath
drawingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
drawingLayer.lineWidth = 3
drawingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

drawingView.layer.addSublayer(drawingLayer)

let drawingLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
drawingLayer2.path = endPoint.CGPath
drawingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
drawingLayer.lineWidth = 3
drawingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

drawingView.layer.addSublayer(drawingLayer2)
```

The problem here is that the result is not how I expected to be, as you can see below I do have two dots, but one is all black (instead of having a red border and white fill) and the other one is green-bordered and has a white fill (as I wanted to be)

[image]

But, *why* is this happening? According to the code I have two separate `CAShapeLayer`s here, which have different properties and which I am adding to the UIView separately

Comment: It's a common problem when you copy&paste some repetitive code that you'll forget to rename the variables and there will be no errors since the copies variables are available at this scope. Have a helper functions to make your code safer and easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've copy/pasted and forgot to rename `drawingLayer` to `drawingLayer2`

```
let drawingLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
drawingLayer2.path = endPoint.CGPath
drawingLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
drawingLayer2.lineWidth = 3
drawingLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

So, `drawingLayer2` is just using default values for `strokeColor`, `lineWidth` and `fillColor`

You could create a function to simplify your code. Instead of copying and pasting, which is error prone.

```
func addDotWithPath(path: UIBezierPath) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let drawingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    drawingLayer.path = path.CGPath
    drawingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    drawingLayer.lineWidth = 3
    drawingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    return drawingLayer
}

drawingView.layer.addSublayer(addDotWithPath(beginPoint))
drawingView.layer.addSublayer(addDitWithPath(endPoint))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let drawingLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
drawingLayer2.path = endPoint.CGPath
drawingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
drawingLayer.lineWidth = 3
drawingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

You simply forgot some drawingLayer **2**